# Using apply function to do claculation in data.frame without change the format of my date column

Tags: r, lapply

This is my data.frame:

```
df<-structure(list(Data = structure(c(18158, 18157, 18156, 18155, 
18152), class = "Date"), A = c(19.46, 19.26, 19.43, 19.44, 
19.1), B = c(49.72, 49.2, 48.45, 47, 51.34), C = c(45.69, 
44.92, 44.12, 43.07, 43), D = c(48.32, 48.02, 47.3, 46.65, 
47.14)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do the following calculation using apply function, **but without extract** the Date column :

```
new.df<-apply(df,2, function(x) (-diff(x)/x[-length(x)]))
```

I am not able to do this because there is a "Date" format column. How can I change my apply function to deal with it, and the result keeps give a dataframe with the first column stills a "Date" format?

Comment: Note that the column name in the  example is `Data` instead of `Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know the position of the 'Date' column, use the indexing method to remove the column

```
f1 <- function(x) (-diff(x)/x[-length(x)])
apply(df[-1], 2, f1)
```

Or to make it less error-prone, remove the column with `name`

```
apply(df[setdiff(names(df), 'Data')], 2, f1)
```

`apply` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can have only single type.  So, what happens is the `Date` class gets coerced to the integer storage mode if it is also included.

If there are `character` columns, all the elements will be converted to `character` and the calculation won't work

The `diff` function returns an output with `length` one less than the `length` of the input and if we need to update the original columns of the dataset, there would be a `length` mismatch.  To avoid that append `NA` at the beginning

```
f2 <- function(x) (c(NA, -diff(x)/x[-length(x)]))
df[-1] <- apply(df[-1],2, f2)
```

If we are creating new columns

```
df[paste0(names(df)[-1], "_diffs")] <- apply(df[-1],2, f2)
```

---

Or to make it more dynamic

```
i1 <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
apply(df[i1], 2,  f1)
```

---

Also, for datasets with multiple types, can use `lapply/sapply`

```
lapply(df[i1], function(x) -diff(x)/x[-length(x)])
```

---

With `dplyr`, we can use `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ c(NA_real_, diff(.)/.[-n()]))
#      Data            A           B            C            D
#1 2019-09-19           NA          NA           NA           NA
#2 2019-09-18 -0.010277492 -0.01045857 -0.016852703 -0.006208609
#3 2019-09-17  0.008826584 -0.01524390 -0.017809439 -0.014993753
#4 2019-09-16  0.000514668 -0.02992776 -0.023798731 -0.013742072
#5 2019-09-13 -0.017489712  0.09234043 -0.001625261  0.010503751
```

if we need to create new columns, place it in a `list` and do the naming as in the `list`

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, list(diffs = ~ c(NA_real_, diff(.)/.[-n()])))
#        Data     A     B     C     D      A_diffs     B_diffs      C_diffs      D_diffs
#1 2019-09-19 19.46 49.72 45.69 48.32           NA          NA           NA           NA
#2 2019-09-18 19.26 49.20 44.92 48.02 -0.010277492 -0.01045857 -0.016852703 -0.006208609
#3 2019-09-17 19.43 48.45 44.12 47.30  0.008826584 -0.01524390 -0.017809439 -0.014993753
#4 2019-09-16 19.44 47.00 43.07 46.65  0.000514668 -0.02992776 -0.023798731 -0.013742072
#5 2019-09-13 19.10 51.34 43.00 47.14 -0.017489712  0.09234043 -0.001625261  0.010503751
```